# Android Studio 3.2.1 (32-bit) doesn't start when I click studio.exe or studio.bat

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

No error, no window popup, nothing. I'm cluless. I've tried setting Environment Variable (JDK_HOME, STUDIO_JDK etc), setting **studio.exe.vmoptions** and reinstall Android Studio and Java. Still won't launch. The weird thing is 2 days ago I can launch the Android Studio without all these things. Now I can't even see what's happening and why it won't launch. Much help needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I didn't knew what was the problem, then I started to run **studio.bat** in cmd and found out the real problem.

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM:
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

So what I did is I created a new Environment Variable

```
Variable : _JAVA_OPTIONS
Value    : -Xmx512M
```

I re-opened cmd and start studio.bat again, this time it gives me new error:

```
jdk required: 'tools.jar' seems to be not in studio classpath.
Please ensure java_home points to jdk rather than jre.
```

And to fix this, I copy tools.jar from **(YOUR JDK PATH)\lib\tools.jar** and paste it to **(Your Android Studio PATH)\lib**
Voila, now I have a functioning IDE.